# DB with User Login and Privileges, Not Working Properly

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database that has various forms, and I decided to restric the use of some of them depending on the user. So I created a login form, and depending on who logs in, some functions in certain forms are disabled or enabled.

The user logs in, and his info is stored in tempvars.

Then on loading other forms, the info is looked up on "Acessos" table to validate what type of user he/she is, and to what he/she has access to.

Despite that it all goes ok when I compile it, when I actually try it, I get a syntax error as shown on the attached image.

Any idea of what's missing? Or where I got it wrong?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)`

If DLookup("Acesso", "tblacessos", "[Tipo ID]=" & TempVars("TipoUtilizador") & " AND Objecto='" & Me.Name & "'") = False Then`

Command5.Visible = False
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, your TempVars function is returning Null. You need to inspect that function, possibly remove an error handling in it until you see whay it is returning Null. I also agree with @pizzettix that you need to add brackets to Objecto

Comment: Thanks @pizzettix. The brackets didn't work.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware the TempVars function should be retriving values. I don't understand why it is not.

Comment: `Private Sub Command8_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblutilizadores", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
rs.FindFirst "[User ID]='" & Me.txtutilizador & "'"
If rs.NoMatch = True Then
MsgBox "Utilizador Inválido", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
Me.txtutilizador.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If rs!Password <> Me.txtpassword Then
MsgBox "Password Inválida", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
TempVars("TipoUtilizador") = rs![Tipo ID].Value`

Comment: Brackets are not needed unless object name contains spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) or is a reserved word. Advise not to use these features in naming convention. Should edit question to show additional info such as code, not in a comment. Have you step debugged?

Comment: `TempVars("TipoUtilizador") = rs![Tipo ID].Value`  I don't see how TempVars is defined. Is it a global user data type? Show us the Type or Dim statement that defines TempVars please. Edit your question and add that code there, instead of these comments

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: @KacireeSoftware, it has no Dim statement, nor a type been defined.

Comment: if TempVars is a function make sure Access can find it.  Make sure TempVars is public and put TempVars in a public code module.  do not put TempVars in a forms code behind.  Access can find public functions declared in public code modules.  Also consider getting the value from TempVars before including it in the string to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok, so honestly I couldn't figure out what the problem was. But, today I rewriten the code that I provided for this question, and it simply worked.  Thanks to everyone who helped.